# Where can I store a cloud config file?

Tags: config, coreos

I'm installing CoreOS on a home computer (for fun), now every time I re-install the OS I have to manually create the a `cloud-config.yaml` file to pass to the install script.

Reading the docs on the CoreOS site it states there is a way to store these files in a repository (seen here: https://coreos.com/docs/cluster-management/setup/adding-users/).

They aren't very clear as to what kind of repository and as I am new to this I was wondering if there was anyone with maybe a "protip" or hopefully a standard approach as to where I can store these files.

If they mean store these files on something like Github then is that a good approach? Or do they mean something a little more private hopefully password protected.

How do you store and retrieve your cloud config files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any HTTP endpoint to store the data.  That means `httpd` or `nginx` behind your firewall or even S3 or [GitHub Gists](http://gist.github.com). Make sure if you use a gist though that you make it secret if you put a SHA password hash though.

As an [example](https://gist.github.com/brianredbeard/ab9449c1c86868f53d5c).  One other thing to remember is that you'll need to use the "[raw](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/brianredbeard/ab9449c1c86868f53d5c/raw/f1bf75a76c3921ee6953fe70ead77073557f3a4a/fleetapi.yml)" version of the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any sort of source repository, including Github. That sentence was mostly intended to push people towards using a pull request type workflow to ensure that only the proper public keys, etc end up on their servers. Handling sensitive secrets in a repo is up to your org's policy, etc.

Very similar to how many people version and work on Chef recipes.